# Root Mean Square Log Error (RMSLE) Interpretation

Tags: predictive-models, model-evaluation

I would like to clarify my understanding of Root Mean Log Squared Error (RMSLE):

$$\text{RMSLE}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left [\ln \left ( \frac{y_{i}+1}{\hat{y_{i}}+1} \right )  \right ]^{2}}$$

RMSLE effectively quantifies the average exponential-multiplicative error. For instance, a model with an RMSLE of $1$ indicates that, on average:

$$\frac{y}{\hat{y}}=e^{\pm 1} \rightarrow y \approx \hat{y} \cdot 2.7^{\pm 1}$$

Essentially, a typical prediction would be off by a factor of $2.7$. Technically, this interpretation is only approximately true because the above equation adds $1$ to both the predicted and actual values to ensure that its domain is $[0,\infty)$. However, when both $y, \hat{y} \gg 1$, the distortion is negligible.

Is this correct??

Comment: The $+1$s are designed to deal with cases where $y_i$ or $\hat y_i$ may potentially be $0$ or slightly less (though still greater than $-1$).  But in such cases you lose the "exponential-multiplicative" interpretation.   If you are sure $y, \hat{y} \gg 1$ then the effect is likely to be small but then the $+1$s become unnecessary.